# Download openerp source code

Tags: odoo

I am newbie to launchpad. I am trying to download source code of OpenERP from this https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp/openerp/package-script

Can anyone point me in the right direction about steps to be followed to download the source branch?

Sorry if I am asking very trivial question. I installed SVN and tried to use the steps in the above given link. But I am getting nothing into my disk.

Thanks in advance.
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Install [bzr](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) and [configure](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/mini-tutorial/) it.

after that you can get the branches from the launchpad using following command in terminal.

```
 bzr branch lp:openobject-server/7.0

 bzr branch lp:openerp-web/7.0

 bzr branch lp:openobject-addons/7.0
```

It will get the required source of OpenERP from the launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the source code from [GITHUB](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/7.0). for more informations check [GitHub-Transition](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/wiki/GitHub-Transition).

To clone 7.0 branch use the following command:

```
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --branch 7.0
```